# pattern match issues with apostrophes

Tags: php, regex

I have an expression that I want to modify. This expression, for the most part does what I want, however, I need to to also match for case insensitive.

I am matching names of people as well as business names. So, the following should be matched and currently is not:

tim's baKeRY

Here is the expression

`#^[A-Z][a-z]+[ -][A-Z](\')?(?(1)[A-Z])[a-z]+$#`

---

**EDIT**

Thanks to Gustav, I edited my expression to:
`#^[a-zA-Z]+[ -][a-zA-Z](\')?(?(1)[a-zA-Z])[a-z]+$#`

This gives me case insensitivity which was part of what I needed but I also need to match something like `tim's bakery`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do `/.../i` in PHP to match case insensitive. If you want to correct what you have though, you need to observe that `[A-Z][a-z]+` will match one initial capital letter and then the rest lower case. If you want to match both in the same, you need to do `[A-Za-z]+`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Gustav, I've edited it so it now looks like this: `#^[a-zA-Z]+[ -][a-zA-Z](\')?(?(1)[a-zA-Z])[a-z]+$#`. This gets me the case insensitivity but how to match something like `tims's balery`?

Comment: I can give you any number of regex patterns that will match `tims's belry`, the question is, what else do you want it to match (and what do you want it not to match)?

Comment: Thanks for the help Gustav. What I'm trying to match are person's names as well as business names. From what I can gather, the code should match any and all common characters that are used in these names. Such as apostrophe, hyphen space and that's about it I think. It's usually the "I think" part that gets me into trouble. :)

Comment: Well, your first regex matchesvery specific things (allowing names such as O'Reilly, from what I can tell), and throwing in `tim's bakery` "and the like" in there is very difficult if you don't know exactly what you want to match. Business names can vary even more than personal names, so I suggest you either figure out exactly what you want to match, or just use something like `/[a-zA-Z'- ]+/` and be happy with that.